# Is $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ smooth on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? (where $f$ and $g$ are smooth on $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two smooth functions. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$. Is $h$ smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

I know that the partial derivatives of $h$ are exists and are continuous, so $h$ is differentiable. But I am not able to prove or disprove that $h$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: For any $j,k$, does $\dfrac{\partial^{j+k}h}{\partial x^j\partial y^k}$ exist and is it continuous?

Comment: The product of two smooth functions is smooth.

Comment: Yes. Product of two functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^2$. But here product of two functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes that is continuous

Answer (score 0):

We have $\dfrac{\partial^{j+k}h}{\partial x^j\partial y^k}(x,y)=f^{(j)}(x)g^{(k)}(y)$ and $f,g$ smooth.

Conclusion ?

Comment: $f^{(j)}(x)g^{(k)}(y)$ is continuous. But Differentiable?

Comment: $f^{(j)}$ and $g^{(k)}$ are differentiable, hence their product is differentiable.